# How to create All-Users.git

Tags: gerrit

I deleted All-Users.git by mistake.And then I can't get all my projects.How can I recover this ? Or how can I recreate All-Users.git, after that how can I get all my other projects?

Comment: All-Users.git has only users data, correct? Why you can't get the projects data (others *.git repositories)?

Comment: To display projects, Gerrit needs to read user and group data to determine whether the current user has access to the projects. I’m afraid you’re out of luck if you don’t have a backup of $GERRIT_HOME/git/All-Users.git on the Gerrit server, or a local copy on a client machine.